# jQuery UI 1.8 Accordion "Active"

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I am using the jQuery UI 1.8 Accordion widget.
When making use of the "active" feature so that when the page loads a particular accordion window will be open I find that if I set it to be "active 3" then the 4th window opens.
Or if I set it to "active " the 3rd window opens.

Anyone know why?
Here is a link to a fiddle ....
http://jsfiddle.net/bbyrdhouse/hZGL7/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is a zero based collection - the first element is '0', second is '1' and so forth.

Answer (score 1):

This is because the `active` property is zero-based. To get the first tab to be active, you set `0`, second tab would be `active: 1` and so on.